# Get largest width of a textblock in a stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

On a button click, I am reading through a CSV file, replacing ',' with '\t' and writing it out to a stackpanel.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < r.variables.Count; i++)
        {
            _people.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = r.variables[i], HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Right });//.ToString() });
            StackPanel stp = new StackPanel() { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };

            TextBlock tb = new TextBlock() {Text = r.variables[i]};

            stp.Children.Add(tb); 

            _secondStack.Children.Add(stp);
        }

        foreach (StackPanel sp in _secondStack.Children)
        {

            foreach (TextBlock tb in sp.Children)
            {
                Size desiredSize = new Size();
                tb.Measure(this.availableSize);
                desiredSize = tb.DesiredSize;
            }
        }
    }
```

From the file, some contain strings that are longer than others, thus the TextBlocks in the header are wider than those TextBlocks below.

How do I get the width of the widest TextBlock in the embedded StackPanel and set the width of all TextBlocks inside the embedded StackPanel to that?

Comment: You are really going to struggle with doing WPF layout calculations in code because it won't have a size untill its rendered onscreen, thats why WPF is meant to be used with the MVVM pricipal, Perhaps you should Use an ItemsControl that will layout the TextBlocks, this will automaticly set them all to the greatest size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the `StackPanel` is populated, this is how you get the largest `Width` and set it for all other `TextBox`es:

```
 double largestWidth = stackPanel.Children.OfType<TextBox>().OrderByDescending(
         textbox => textbox.ActualWidth).First().ActualWidth;

 foreach (var textBox in stackPanel.Children.OfType<TextBox>())
 {
      textBox.ActualWidth = largestWidth;
 }
```

Comment: how do I change the double largestWidth = stackPanel.Children.OfType<TextBox>() part since the TextBlocks are in a StackPanel inside a StackPanel?

Comment: Give the `StackPanel` that has the `TextBox`es in it a name, then replace `stackPanel` with that name.

Comment: You should use `ActualWidth` as `Width` will be `NaN` unless it is set explicitly already